# What does compiler do when performing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

What does compiler do behind the scene (at assembly level) when performing lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is the lvalue read into a temporary memory (register)?

Comment: Almost all compilers can generate assembly files where you can see exactly what code it generates.

Comment: Surely this depends on the compiler, the computers architecture, optimization level or if it is having debug info in the binary

Comment: Nothing. Every lvalue is an rvalue. The converse does not hold. The distinguishing feature of a lvalue is that it has an address as well as a value.

Comment: This question is a little like "what does the human body do behind the scenes (at the chemical level) when performing a conversion from 'fit' to 'out of shape'" - it's broad, skips a few levels of abstraction, and does not talk about a piece of knowledge that is useful.

Comment: @EJP: 3.10/1: "Every expression belongs to exactly one of the fundamental classifications in this taxonomy: lvalue, xvalue,
or prvalue." And there is no shared ancestry between _lvalue_ and _prvalue_ such that an _lvalue_ could also be an _rvalue_. So, your assertion that `every lvalue is an rvalue` is patently false. Perhaps you're getting confused by 3.10/2: "Whenever a glvalue appears in a context where a prvalue is expected, the glvalue is converted to a prvalue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the compiler does in each specific case will depend on the compiler implementation, the current optimization level, the exact workings of optimizations in effect at that point, and more.

But basically, lvalue to rvalue conversion corresponds to reading the memory content (roughly representing the rvalue) from the address it is stored at (roughly representing the lvalue).